# #include<ESP8266WiFi.h> showing error message

Tags: esp8266

i was trying to send some data to a webpage via esp8266wifi module connected to arduino uno. My sketch contains a header file .After searching online I could get the library Arduino-master.zip from github. I extracted the files and put it in inside the directory arduino->hardware->arduino->avr->libraries.but even then it was showing me the error message like this:

fatal error: ESP8266WiFi.h: No such file or directory

 #include 

                         ^

compilation terminated.

exit status 1
Error compiling for board Arduino/Genuino Uno.

How can I remove this error. please refrain from technical words as i am new to this language. Thank you.

**EDIT**: After adding esp8266WiFi.h in the library i got out from that error message .But it showed me a new one

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\ESP8266WiFi\src/ESP8266WiFiType.h:26:19: fatal error: queue.h: No such file or directory

 #include 

                   ^

compilation terminated.

exit status 1
Error compiling for board Arduino/Genuino Uno.

I dont know how to come out of this error. some [websites](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=442690.0) give a solution but it didn't worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

That library is part of the ESP8266 core. It's not for the Arduino, but for programming the ESP8266 as a standalone unit without an Arduino connected to it.

Answer (score 0):

ESP8266WiFi part of the project Arduino Core here: https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino Arduino Core provides support for the ESP8266 to be used with Arduino IDE through the boards manager facility. So its libraries are for the ESP8266 not the Uno.

If you are interested in communicating with the ESP8266 over serial using its AT+ command firmware then you just send them as strings over serial.

```
Serial1.println("AT+GMR");
while(Serial1.available() == 0) {
  delay(1);
}
while(Serial1.available() > 0) {
  Serial.write(Serial1.read());
}
```

Comment: That's a terrible serial routine there...

Comment: @Majenko It's an example. Edit in a better one if you want.